# track location of multiple people in phonegap?

Tags: cordova, geolocation

I am developing android apps in phonegap and in that I would like to know all my sales person location in sales manager mobile(means in apps). when i click on the tab like get location in my apps then apps will show me the location list of sales person.
I read phonegap documentation but in that we only track the individual mobile.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess,
                                     [geolocationError],
                                     [geolocationOptions]);
```

we can not track the other device location. Please give some some procedure to do this above task.

Q.1) Is there any api for to get the location of other people? 
Q.2) how GPS Tracker android apps work like above task?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what your asking with just PhoneGap alone. You will need to set up a server, have the app on your sale people's phones send their locations to the server, and then pass it back down to you. This is how tracking applications work; all the data must be sent, stored, and served from somewhere.

You could use something like [Parse](https://parse.com/) to handle all the transactions and storage, but it also wouldn't be difficult to build it yourself if that is what you wanted.

Comment: yes I agreed but some apps having same functionality for e.g. GPS Tracker Pro. GPS Tracking Pro: Keep Track of Your Family, Friends & Phones With GPS Technology how this apps work.

Comment: They work by having the user send their location to a server, then having that server send the location back to whoever is requesting it and has the proper permissions.